# trigger method when mulitple computed are true / filled (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, computed-properties

I need following: I want to trigger a function in my `methods` **only** when `test1`, `test2` and `test3` are filled. Otherwise nothing should happen.

I've tried to do this in my `computed` and than with a `watcher` but it's not working out for me.

Hopefully someone could help me out.

```
computed: {
  test1() {
    return this.$store.state.test1; 
  },

  test2() {
    return this.$store.state.test2;
  },

  test3() {
    return this.$store.state.test3;
  },

  check_data() {
    return this.test1 && this.test2 && this.test3;
  },
},

watch: {
  check_data() {
    this.trigger_method()
  },
},
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to watch? The way you watch it ended up watching a value called `true` or `false`, so if one value change, it might not triggering the method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the deep watcher?

```
watch: {
  check_data: {
     deep: true, 
     handler(newValue, oldValue) {
        // do something
     }
  }

},
```